# Numerical implementation of ODE differs largely from analytical solution

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the ODE of a free fall including air resistance.

I therefore defined my ODE as:

```
def f(v, g, k, m):
    return g - k/m * v**2
```

which in my opinion should represent the system correctly because

```
m*a = m*g -k*v**2
```

where `a=vdot`.

Now I solve this ODE using the explicit Euler method like this:

```
h = 0.1
t = np.arange(0, 1000 + h, h)
v0 = 0

g = 9.81
k = 0.1
m = 1.

# Explicit Euler Method
v_num = np.zeros(len(t))
v_num[0] = 0

x_num = np.zeros(len(t))
x_num[0] = 100

for i in range(0, len(t) - 1):
    v_num[i + 1] = v_num[i] + h*f(v_num[i], g, k, m)
    x_num[i + 1] = x_num[i] - v_num[i + 1] * h
```

On first glance this seems to work fine. However I plotted it against the analytical solution of the ODE that I found online

```
v_ana = m*g*(1.-np.exp(-k/m*t))/k
```

And they seem to differ largely, as shown below.

[image: Chart of numerical and analytical solution of ODE. Analytical solution reaches much higher terminal velocity]

Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to scicomp! If I where you, I'd skip the air resistance for a moment to see if the time-stepping is correct (compare to analytical solution). Then add the air-resistance term. I'm suspicius of the fact that the air-resistance term still contains the mass m..

Comment: Hi @MPIchael thanks for your comment! Do you mean in the differential equation `m*a = m*g -k*v**2`? But how would it get cancelled out of that equation? The analytical solution I just took from https://wethestudy.com/mathematics/free-falling-bodies-differential-equations/

Comment: In the link with your analytical solution, the differential equation is `m*a = m*g -k*v` but you use the term `-k*v**2` to account for air resistance.

Comment: OP's analytical solution doesn't match the ODE. For the quadratic velocity drag force, the analytical solution is derived here: https://philosophicalmath.wordpress.com/2017/10/21/terminal-velocity-derivation/

Comment: You are all correct. I didn't pay attention that the motion equation looks different for low Reynolds numbers.

Comment: Also, your gravity appears to be pointing upward.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I'm Australian ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the link that you have posted in the comment, I guess your function definition is not correct.

```
def f(v, g, k, m):
    return g - k/m * v
```

Hope the above should fix the issue, but also when using explicit time stepping, be wary to choose the time step such that it is stable.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't pay attention that the motion equation looks different for low Reynolds numbers. So basically I implemented the low Reynolds analytical solution and the high Reynolds numerical solution.

Answer (score 7):

The equation for the square resistance can be easily solved by remembering the pattern $$(e^y)''=e^y\,(y''+y'^2)$$ and considering $u=\exp(-cx)$. This gives $\dot u=cvu$ (with $v=-\dot x$) and
$$\ddot u=cu(\dot v+cv^2).$$
With $c=\frac{k}{m}$ (and $\dot u(0)=cu(0)v(0)=0$) one finally gets
$$
\ddot u = cgu, ~~~ u(t)=A\cosh(\sqrt{cg}t),\\ v(t)=\frac{\dot u}{cu}=\sqrt{\frac gc}\tanh(\sqrt{cg} t),
\\
x(t)=-\frac1c\ln(u(t))=\frac1c[-\ln(A)-\ln(\cosh(\sqrt{cg}t))]
$$
For large $t$ the velocity stabilizes at $\sqrt{\frac gc}=\sqrt{98.1}$ and the height drops linearly accordingly with speed about $10 m/s$.

More precisely, for large $t$
$$
x(t)\approx x(0)+\frac{\ln2}{c}-\sqrt{\frac gc}t,
$$
which corrects the $t=0$ intercept of the asymptotic line to account for the initially slower fall.

Comment: +1 for such a delightful substitution which is much faster than the partial fraction expansion that is often seen.

Comment: It comes from considering the equation as Riccati-equation for $v$.